# Filtering a stream using String predicate

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to make a method that receives List of DataFiles then filters it using String predicate on one of its fields and returns List of DataFiles instead of Strings.

Here is my code:

```
public static List<DataFile> someMethod(List<DataFile> dataFiles) {
    return dataFiles
            .stream()
            .map(DataFile::getFileName)
            .filter(companyAndDateFilter(date, BLABLA, LALALA))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Predicate<String> companyAndDateFilter(LocalDate date, String... companyNames) {
    String companies = getCompaniesAsString(companyNames);
    String formattedDate = formatTheDate(date);
    Pattern pattern =  Pattern
            .compile("^(" + companies + ")_(" + formattedDate + ")");
    LOGGER.info("Filtering files using RegEx: " + pattern.pattern());
            return pattern.asPredicate();
}
```

When I do `.map(DataFile::getFileName)` I transform my stream into `Stream<String>` but I would like to leave it as `Stream<DataFile>` and still use filter (which is `Predicate<String>`) on that `DataFile::getFileName`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static List<DataFile> someMethod(List<DataFile> dataFiles) {
    Predicate<String> hasCompanyAndDate = companyAndDateFilter(date, BLABLA, LALALA);

    return dataFiles.stream()
        .filter(dataFile -> hasCompanyAndDate.test(dataFile.getFileName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```